# GUI frame is huge, doesn't match my design in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Sorry for the lame title, couldn't think of a better way to word it. Basically, I'm learning GUIs in java and using NetBeans and I have a problem I haven't been able to search, and my google fu is failing me. Basically, when I design a new window I can get it exactly how I want it

[image]

and then when I go to run it, it comes out huge but it's not maximized, just a giant frame

[image]

I've tried manipulating properties that sound like they would help with no luck. Can anyone offer some advice? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Wanted to add, this isn't specific to this program, it does it with any GUI's I try to make, leading me to believe it's some setting in Netbeans that I can't find an answer to.

Here is the GUI code:

```
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    calculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    customerTypeTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    subtotalTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    discountPercentTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    discountAmountTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    totalTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Customer Type:");

    jLabel2.setText("Subtotal:");

    jLabel3.setText("Discount Percent:");

    jLabel4.setText("Discount Amount:");

    jLabel5.setText("Total:");

    calculateButton.setText("Calculate");
    calculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            calculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    exitButton.setText("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    discountPercentTxt.setEditable(false);
    discountPercentTxt.setFocusable(false);

    discountAmountTxt.setEditable(false);
    discountAmountTxt.setFocusable(false);

    totalTxt.setEditable(false);
    totalTxt.setFocusable(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))
                        .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(discountAmountTxt)
                            .addComponent(totalTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 108, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(discountPercentTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 108, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(subtotalTxt)
                            .addComponent(customerTypeTxt))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(calculateButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(exitButton)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(customerTypeTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(subtotalTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(discountPercentTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(discountAmountTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(totalTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(calculateButton)
                .addComponent(exitButton))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

And more requested code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new InvoiceForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problems.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still really new to this. I read the link you posted about SSCCE and I'm not sure what all of my code I should post. It's 3 separate classes, but this is related to the GUI, so should I just post that info?

Comment: Can you show the code where the window is made visible? It's probably in main(). I just ran your code in Eclipse, and the frame opens with preferred sizing, in other words, it looks normal, not a huge window like your screen shots.

Comment: Done, I edited it up top.

Comment: Remove the `for each`, replace with this: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());`, see if that works

Comment: I removed the for each loop and replaced it with just the try block and the code you suggested and I get the same results. I feel like it's some option that is not working properly with the IDE and I'm starting to wonder if it's not actually the code, considering all the UI stuff is auto-generated.

Comment: Be careful with GUI graphic dsigners as it is hard to get exactly what you want, and moreover, they produce code that is hard to understand and debug. Obviously the issue here is that NetBeans did not understand what the behavior should be when enlarging the panel size: by default, it decided to have the left column stick to the left and the right column stick to the right, which explains your screenshot. I would suggest using a better layout manager for this (eg DesignGridLayout).

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would forget about NetBeans designer and I would code the GUI with [DesignGridLayout](https://java.net/projects/designgridlayout/); just replace all the block of code between following line (included):

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
```

and the following line (excluded, it must be kept):

```
pack();
```

with the following block of code:

```
DesignGridlLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout(getContentPane());
layout.row().grid(jLabel1).add(customerTypeTxt);
layout.row().grid(jLabel2).add(subtotalTxt);
layout.row().grid(jLabel3).add(discountPercentTxt);
layout.row().grid(jLabel4).add(discountAmountTxt);
layout.row().grid(jLabel5).add(totalTxt);
layout.emptyRow();
layout.row().center().add(calculateButton, exitButton);
```

You should get exactly the UI you want and enlarging should work as expected.

Don't search for a grphical designer for DesignGridLayout, you will find none as this is one layout manager created to be usable directly through coding, and coding with it is just super easy.

Answer (score 0):

You should post some code, but I'll take a stab anyway: at the end of your GUI code, call this:

```
pack();
```

...to resize the frame based on preferred size and layout of its components.

Comment: That is actually already there. I'll edit my main post to include the auto-generated GUI stuff.